# Validation and getting a value of a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

Good Morning,

I'm working on wpf application and i need to get the value of a textbox and check that it's number in the same time ! i checked the tutos and the forums on the net and i found that`

```
private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
        e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
    }
```

and here is the code in my XAML code

```
<TextBox x:Name="sb" Width="50" Height="20" PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox" />
```

but i can't see how i can link between that method and the object ( textbox ) that i want to get the value from . Do i need to use a proprety on the XAML Code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do i need to use a proprety on the XAML Code ?

Indeed, you need a property in your ViewModel if you are using the MVVM pattern.

After implementing the property on your ViewModel, make sure you provide the notify functionality by implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Bind your property to the Text attribute of your TextBox (Two-Way in order to transmit changes made in your View to the ViewModel and vice versa) and include your validation in the set method of your property.

Comment: i'm not using MVVM pattern , what should i do ?

Comment: Take a look at MVVM and consider using it. It will make your life easier and your applications more maintainable.

Comment: i need to implement the proprety of getting the value on MVVM ?

Comment: Yes. You may want to take a look at some tutorials or guides regarding MVVM first.

Comment: is there any other way to do without using MVVM ?

Comment: Yes, see the answer from user3503711. I wouldn't recommend using that since it lacks clarity and maintainability but that's your decision.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) //textbox1=your text box name
{
    char ch = e.KeyChar;
    if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This code will not let you to input anything except numeric values!

Comment: WPF was not meant to be event driven. I highly advise against using the event driven style even though it may work here.

Comment: what do you mean by event driven ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `PreviewTextInput` event, you can get new text from `e.Text` and already entered text from `sender` parameter which referenced the object that raise the event (your `TextBox` in this case) :

```
private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    String newText = e.Text;
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    String existingText = textBox.Text;
    .......
    .......
}
```